# Connect to local Oracle database from online website

Tags: python, database, django, oracle, database-connection

I have a "local" Oracle database in my work network. I also have a website at a hosting service.

Can I connect to the 'local' Oracle database from the hosting service? Or does the Oracle database need to be at the same server as my website?

At my work computer I can connect to the Oracle database with a host name, username, password, and port number.

Comment: do u static ip to ur system

Comment: It can depend on how your hosting is setup, but if it is allowed you will need the following.  1) Static IP, or Dynamic DNS setup so your home server can be found regularly.  2) Port forwarding on your router to allow traffic to reach the server.  3) The willingness to expose your home systems to the dangers of the internet

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on how your hosting is setup, but if it is allowed you will need the following.

1. Static IP, or Dynamic DNS setup so your home server can be found regularly.
2. Port forwarding on your router to allow traffic to reach the server.
3. The willingness to expose your home systems to the dangers of the internet

Strictly speaking a static IP/Dynamic DNS setup is not required, but if you don't use that kind of setup, you will have to change the website configuration every time your home system changes IPs, the frequency of which depends on your ISP.  It's also worth noting that many ISP's consider running servers on your home network a violation of the terms of service for residential customers, but in practice as long as you aren't generating too much traffic, it's not usually an issue.

With Port forwarding on your router, you can specify traffic incoming on a particular port be redirected to a specific internal address:port on your network, (e.g. myhomesystem.com:12345 could be redirected to 192.168.1.5:1521)

Once those are in place, you can use the static IP, or the Dynamic DNS entry as the hostname to connect to.